# Can Whatsapp messages be restored from email chat history?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My Whatsapp chats got wiped after a ROM flash that resulted in a soft brick. The other person uses Windows Phone 8, and I have an email from that mobile with the chat history txt file. Can I restore the messages on my phone with this file, perhaps by editing the DB file that Whatsapp backups create? Just the message text would be great, I do not care for the dates or other metadata.

This is probably not an easy task, and I'm ready to roll up my sleeves and dig in. Any general pointers to get started would be great.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp uses SQLite databases for recording chat history. It's not possible to restore without writing custom code to convert plain text into sqlite database accepted by whatsapp. I don't know of any such tool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that but it's going to be a really tough work.

Try using DB Sqlite browser to access the mgstore.db file in your rooted phone by saving the same file on PC. Then you can create new records in the sqlite file and add on your old messages to your chat history.

Answer (score 1):

`msgstore.db` is no more plain zipped `sqlite` database.
It is now encrypted (with `crypt8`) too using the keys from the device WhatsApp was installed on.

So manually injecting can be really difficult though not impossible once WhatsApp is installed.

I suggest you refer to the text file when you need it, and don't worry about putting it back in WhatsApp.