# Create whatsapp database from emailed conversation?

Tags: email, whatsapp-messenger, restore

I recently switched phones and lost most of my whatsapp conversations. However, some of them I emailed to myself previously. Is there anyway to turn the text file sent by email into a database so I can restore it to the whatsapp app?

Answer (score 0):

Nope you cannot do it. This has been explained in a [previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62755/can-whatsapp-messages-be-restored-from-email-chat-history?rq=1) which should help you understand the reason.